# How do I escape the '+' characters in an AutoHotKey, with the date script?

Tags: autohotkey

I use AutoHotKey to display actual date.
here is the code :

```
:*C:]d::  ; This hotstring replaces "]d" with the current date and time via the commands below.
FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,, yyyy‑MM‑dd ‒ HH'H'mm '(UTC+1)' ; It will look like 2005-01-09 15H53 (UTC+1)
SendInput %CurrentDateTime%
return
```

But the result miss the '+', I used "`" or "",
both not vrog.

Thank pro help.
Good day and long and happy life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [text send mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Text).

```
:*C:]d::  ; This hotstring replaces "]d" with the current date and time via the commands below.
    FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,, yyyy‑MM‑dd ‒ HH'H'mm '(UTC+1)' ; It will look like 2005-01-09 15H53 (UTC+1)
    SendInput, {Text}%CurrentDateTime%
return
```

---

Also, if you'd want to ditch the legacy AHK syntax, you'd do this:

```
:*C:]d::
    FormatTime, CurrentDateTime, , % "yyyy‑MM‑dd ‒ HH'H'mm '(UTC+1)'"
    SendInput, % "{Text}" CurrentDateTime
return
```

Comment: Tʰangə juə vɛruə mə‑tʃə !  